# Converting DateDIF in Excel to SQL DateDiff

Tags: sql, datediff

Excel Formula:
=DATEDIF(I2,TODAY(),"y")&" years "&DATEDIF(I2,TODAY(),"ym")&" months "&DATEDIF(I2,TODAY(),"md")&" days"

Format looks as:
2 years 9 months 6 days

Wanting this in a SQL Query.

Thoughts?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not a DBMS product. In standard SQL this would `current_timestamp - i2` (which would return an `interval` data type).

Answer (score 1):

In TSQL you can write as:

```
-- In case your date column has time also use Datetime for @I2 instead
DECLARE @I2 AS DATE
SET @I2 = '11/9/2014'

-- In TSQL GETDATE() returns current date and time
SELECT CAST (
               DATEDIFF(YY,@I2,GETDATE()) 
               - CASE WHEN (MONTH(@I2) > MONTH(GETDATE())) 
                             OR (MONTH(@I2) = MONTH(GETDATE())
                            AND DAY(@I2) > DAY(GETDATE())) 
                 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
               AS VARCHAR(4)
            )  +' Years ' +       
       CAST (
               datediff(month, @I2, GETDATE()) 
               - CASE WHEN DAY(@I2) > DAY(GETDATE()) 
                 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                AS VARCHAR(4)
             ) +' Months ' +
         CAST(
              DATEDIFF(d, 
                  DATEADD(m, 
                  datediff(month, @I2, GETDATE()) 
                  - CASE WHEN DAY(@I2) > DAY(GETDATE()) 
                  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                  , @I2)
                , GETDATE())
               AS VARCHAR(4)
             ) +' Days '
```

Comment: This has me very close... It is showing as example:  2 Years 26 months 22 Days

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: It would seem that excel does, in fact, [have a bug](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/datedif-function-25dba1a4-2812-480b-84dd-8b32a451b35c)!

> Warning: Excel provides the DATEDIF function in order to support older workbooks from Lotus 1-2-3. The DATEDIF function may calculate incorrect results under certain scenarios. Please see the known issues section of this article for further details.

For what it's worth, I had to tweak mine a bit to get it to work as expected. The below works 99% of the time, but can be off by anywhere from 1-3 days as far as I can tell. I ran 1500+ unit tests and only 15 failed within that range.

For example, this date range 12/31/1973-12/5/2019 is off by one day. Either that, or excel has a bug!

```sql
SELECT CAST (
              DATEDIFF(YY,@I2,GetDate()) 
               - CASE WHEN (MONTH(@I2) > MONTH(GetDate())) 
                             OR (MONTH(@I2) = MONTH(GetDate())
                            AND DAY(@I2) > DAY(GetDate())) 
                 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
               AS VARCHAR(4)
            )  + ' Years ' +
       CAST (
               datediff(month, @I2, GetDate()) 
               - CASE WHEN DAY(@I2) > DAY(GetDate()) 
                 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                 -
                 (DATEDIFF(YY,@I2,GetDate()) 
               - CASE WHEN (MONTH(@I2) > MONTH(GetDate())) 
                             OR (MONTH(@I2) = MONTH(GetDate())
                            AND DAY(@I2) > DAY(GetDate())) 
                 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 12
                AS VARCHAR(4)
             ) + ' Months ' +
         CAST(
              DATEDIFF(d, 
                  DATEADD(m, 
                  datediff(month, @I2, GetDate()) 
                  - CASE WHEN DAY(@I2) > DAY(GetDate()) 
                  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                  , @I2)
                , GetDate())
               AS VARCHAR(4)
             ) + ' Days '
```